# CSS transform perspective rotateX with transition rapidly hover in out glitch

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

Here is my code.

```css
.ground {
        height: 250px;
        width: 250px;
        background-color: tomato;
        margin: 50vh auto;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
    }

    .floor-1 {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: turquoise;
        transition: transform 3s;
    }

    .floor-1:hover {
        transform-origin: left center;
        transform: perspective(50em) rotateX(180deg);
    }
```

```html
<div class="ground">
    <div class="floor-1">Hello</div>
</div>
```

Now when i try hover in and out 5-10 times is 2-3 s it gives me weird behavior. Div floor-1 nearly about to come out of screen. Why this is happening and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have `persepctive` initially on the element or this one will also have transition creating the bad effect you are getting. Same thing for `transform-origin`.

```css
.ground {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: tomato;
  margin: 50vh auto;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.floor-1 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: turquoise;
  transition: transform 3s;
  transform-origin: left center;
  transform: perspective(50em) rotateX(0deg);
}

.floor-1:hover {
  transform: perspective(50em) rotateX(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="ground">
  <div class="floor-1">Hello</div>
</div>
```

You can also add the perspective on the parent element:

```css
.ground {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: tomato;
  margin: 50vh auto;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  perspective:50em;
  perspective-origin:left center;
}

.floor-1 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: turquoise;
  transition: transform 3s;
  transform:  rotateX(0deg);
}

.floor-1:hover {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="ground">
  <div class="floor-1">Hello</div>
</div>
```